# Ros-groovy packages not found for beglebone black ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build ROS on a Beaglebone black.  Here is the history:

12  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
13  wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
14  sudo apt-get update
15  sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop
or
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-base

fails with:

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-base
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-ros-base

Here is the ros-latest.list:
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main

I have been successful on both amd64 and Raspberry Pi ubuntu running 12.04  Not sure what is missing here.

I note

sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall

and

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial git-core man parted diff

worked ok.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66063/ros-groovy-packages-not-found-for-beglebone-black-ubuntu-12.04/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-15**:
@DrBot, you mentioned running Ubuntu on a Raspberry PI ? AKAIK, ubuntu did not support (12.04 at least) ARM6. Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If running on a BeagleBoard Black, you'll probably want the ARM builds of Ubuntu. Instructions to install can be found on the [ROS Ubuntu ARM install page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM).

The big difference is using:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ahendrix-mirror/ubuntu precise main
```

instead of:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
```

---

Originally posted by [baalexander](https://answers.ros.org/users/143/baalexander/) with karma: 233 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2